# I am Using Ngroute To Show The Json Data But it Does Not Work

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

here is my retails.htm:

```
<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#categories">categories</a>
<a href="#departments">departments</a>
<a href="#digital_marketing">digital_marketing</a>

<div class="ng-view"></div>

<script>

  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "main.htm"

})
.when("/categories/", {
    templateUrl : "categories.htm"


})
.when("/departments/", {
    templateUrl : "departments.htm"


})
.when("/digital_marketing/", {
    templateUrl : "digital_marketing.htm"

});
});
```

categories.htm:

```
<div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="customersCtrl3">

<table border="1">
  <b><tn>categories</tn></b>
  <tr>
    <th>dept_id</th>
    <th>category_name</th>
    <th>category_discription</th>
    <th>current time</th>
    <th>Id</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in categories">
    <td>{{ x.dept_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.category_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.category_discription }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.currenttime }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

 <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp2', []);
  app.controller('customersCtrl3', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:8081/listtables").then(function (response) {
    $scope.categories = response.data.categories;
  });
  });
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

when i run retails.htm and click on categories it does not any data.it just show the blank table.
Here is only one code i.e cateogries.htm. i want do to same with departments and digital_marketing.

http://localhost:8081/listtables is node js file running on the localhost.

Comment: Have you checked that response is successful? Check network panel or attach `catch` handler to request.

Comment: if i only run categories.html the it works.

Comment: but when i run retials.htm it does not show data in tables.

Comment: how to do that?? i already attached retails.html.

Comment: i just want to make a single page app.or want to fetch data from single page which has different links.

Comment: My bad, sorry, what if you run it as one module? You okay with that, or you need separate modules?

Comment: I see that you're defining new one in categories, you can write `angular.module('myApp').controller(...` and remove module definition from `categories.htm`, it's at least simplify current code.